# Calculate the perimeter of a polygon

Tags: arcobjects

I have a feature layer with land parcels. Each parcel is a polygon. So, I want to calculate the perimeter of each polygon using VBA and ArcObjects. Is there any ready code in VBA and ArcObjects to do this?

Any help please?

Thanks
Deme

Comment: Hi Demetris, if the reply to your previous question was satisfactory, can you please mark it as an answer before you ask a new question. This keeps the answering spirit of participants alive...

Comment: @Ujj Six hours is a little hasty!  It's wise for questioners to wait some period--a few days usually--before accepting answers, because good new ones continue to come in.  Also, SE sites never have asked that everybody accept all answers before asking new questions.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [ICurve3 interface](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/arcobjects/esrigeometry/ICurve3.htm).  [Here is a full ArcObjects sample](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/arcobjects/esrigeometry/ICurve_Property_Example.htm).

```
Dim dblPerimeter as double
Dim pCurve as ICurve3
Set pCurve = pYourPolygon    
dblPerimeter = pCurve.Length
```

[**Update - Select feature, code example link:**](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=146594)

Comment: Thank you for that code. However, what I have to do before that; I mean I have just to write a code to select the certain polygon?

Comment: @Demetris, I will update my answer with a select feature code example.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. So, the new code will be complete to check it?

Answer (score 1):

All polygons have a length property, so you can simply access that.